# Как прижать элементы к центрированному элементу?

Tags: css

```
.container>span.a+span.b+span.c
```

Как на css сделать так чтобы `span.b` был по центру `.container` который растянут на всю ширину, а `span.a` и `span.c` прижимались по краям?
При чем нельзя просто их центрировать, т.к. размеры `span.b` могут меняться, но он должен быть всегда по центру.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Положить их внутрь центрированного и использовать absolute.

```css
body { 
  text-align: center;
}

.c {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4em;
  background: silver;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

.l { position: absolute; right: 100%; border: 1px solid; }
.r { position: absolute; left: 100%; border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<div class=c>
  <div class=l>12345678901234567890</div>
  <div class=r>123</div>
  Some centered content
</div>
```

Comment: можете пример показать, а то кажется что у Вас сил на последнее предложение не хватило..

Comment: @vas, я добавил, но вообще, сразу ставить минус как-то не очень хорошо. Мог бы сначала подождать реакции на комментарий.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вы имели в виду следующее поведение.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.a, .c {
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.a:before {
  content: "a";
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.c:after {
  content: "ccccccccc"; 
  color: green;
  position: absolute;

}

.b {
  color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="a"></span>
  <span class="b">bbbb</span>
  <span class="c"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```css
div.container {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="a">
      Lorem ipsum.
  </span>
  
  <span class="b">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum.
  </span>
  <span class="c">
      Lorem ipsum.
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: а Вы в своем примере поменяйте контент местами первый на второй и посмотрите что будет.

Comment: @vas А как вы хотите? Вы думаете у вас левый спан будет большим, но при этом чтобы он не влиял на центральный? Делайте тогда отдельные блоки, вот и все, а минуса и я могу ставить.

Comment: для начала я хочу чтобы отвечающие были не настолько обессиленные чтобы силы хватило дочитать до конца два предложения. Судя по всему Вы по заголовку отвечаете.

Comment: покажите как сделать с разными блоками?